# Put Object to S3 Bucket of another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are able to put objects into our S3 Bucket.

But now we have a requirement that we need to put these Object directly to an S3 Bucket which belongs to a different account and different region.

Here we have few questions:

- Is this possible?
- If possible what changes we need to do for this?

They have provided us Access Key, Secret Key, Region, and Bucket details.

Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If they've provided you with access key and secret key for their account then this is not cross account. What is not working for you?

Comment: how we need to configure their access and secrete key in our environment.Because we already have our Bucket and region details.

Comment: @jarmod We want to directly put into their bucket, We are not copying from our Bucket to theirs. Is this possible?

Comment: If they gave you access key and secret key (but no session token) then that represents an IAM user in their account. You haven't provided any indication of what your environment is, but typically you would configure these credentials either in [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) or [into a file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) named `~/.aws/credentials`. That way the awscli and all AWS SDKs can pick up the credentials. This isn't much different to what you do to put to your own buckets.

Comment: You are right it's an IAM user in their account.

Comment: @jarmod Our EC2 instance is having an IAM Role. Now if we configure their IAM details in ~/.aws/credentials then how we can explicitly tell that to use which IAM. We are using Java 8

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html. Bigger picture, you shouldn’t be sharing IAM user credentials - you should ideally be using cross account roles. You can read the doc for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IAM credentials are associated with a single AWS Account.

When you launch your own Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned IAM Role, it will receive access credentials that are associated with *your* account.

To write to another account's Amazon S3 bucket, you have two options:

**Option 1: Your credentials + Bucket Policy**

The owner of the destination Amazon S3 bucket can add a **Bucket Policy** on the bucket that permits access by your IAM Role. This way, you can just use the normal credentials available on the EC2 instance.

**Option 2: Their credentials**

It appears that you have been given access credentials for *their* account. You can use these credentials to access their Amazon S3 bucket.

As detailed on [Working with AWS Credentials - AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html), you can provide these credentials in several ways. However, if you are using BOTH the credentials provided by the IAM Role AND the credentials that have been given to you, it can be difficult to 'switch between' them. (I'm not sure if there is a way to tell the Credentials Provider to switch between a profile stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` file and those provided via instance metadata.)

Thus, the easiest way is to **specify the Access Key and Secret Key when creating the S3 client**:

```java
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key_id");
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                        .build();
```

It is generally not a good idea to put credentials in your code. You should load them from a configuration file.

Comment: Hi, I also have similar requirement in my project. The above steps are fine but just one thing I want to know, is the access key & secret key fixed or they are liable to change? If they change , then how to configure the credentials in our project?

Comment: @DibyoChatterjee Please create a new question rather than asking in a comment on an old question. Or, search for answers that mention `aws configure` -- it's a way of saving credentials to a configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You need to allow cross account S3 put operation in bucket's policy.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/#:%7E:text=Using%20cross-account%20IAM%20roles,AWS%20account%20or%20AWS%20services.) is a blog by AWS. It should help you in setting up cross account put action.